# Is only one user able to flag a flag as invalid?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

As it is now, only one user is allowed to disagree with the original flag; who selects "invalid flag" when somebody already selected it is disagreeing with the original flag, but also with who is flagging the flag as invalid.

If this is the case, then other users cannot agree that the original flag is invalid. Did I misunderstand it, or is it really so?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *invalid* flag puts you on the same side as the first *invalid* flag—it doesn't mean that you're disagreeing with the initial *invalid* flag as well.

Comment: I guess I took "I do not agree with the existing flags" as meaning "I do not agree with all the existing flags."